# How is/are God/Gods in the Star Wars canon

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

I don't recall anyone ever mentioning anything about any gods anywhere, but clearly the people in the Star Wars -verse believe in a higher being demonstrated with the Vice-Admiral's "God be with you" as a final farewell and good luck.

Comment: Poe Dameron also said "godspeed", and mentioned hell (as in "what the hell is ______?"). Those both seemed out of context in a Star Wars movie.

Comment: @BrettFromLA Han tells a rebel guard "Then I'll see you in hell" in *Empire Strikes Back*. (And Luke says "Oh, God, my uncle. How am I ever                         going to explain this?" after in the scene in *Star Wars* after Obi-Wan invites him to come to Alderaan.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The idea of gods certainly exists in the Galaxy far far away, there are several examples of people worshipping gods or making reference to gods. The Jedi in *The Last Jedi* are referred to as "a religion" however in lieu of a deity they worship The Force.

Examples of gods or deities in canon include:

- C-3PO being worshipped as a god by the Ewoks in *The Return of the Jedi*
- The Gungans are known to have a pantheon of gods with preists that have significant possibility to gain power.
- In Episode 12 of Season 1 of *The Clone Wars* TV show, Dooku refers to Florrum as a "godforsaken planet".
- On Mortis "incredibly powerful" force-wielders are referenced to be god-like, from the 15th, 16th and 17th Episodes of Season 3 of *The Clone Wars*

  > and were drawn into a paradise realm inhabited by unspeakably powerful Force-wielders. These god-like beings were locked in an eternal struggle for dominance, which made Mortis the fulcrum of the entire galaxy and the Force.
  >   <sub>[Mortis - Star Wars Data Bank](http://www.starwars.com/databank/mortis)</sub>
- In companion books to the Force Awakens, the [Church of the Force](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Church_of_the_Force) (most prominently seen when Lor San Tekka's village of worshippers is destroyed in The Force Awakens) believe in the requirement of the return of the Jedi to restore balance to The Force. A similar but opposite worship is the [Acolytes of the Beyond](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Acolytes_of_the_Beyond) who worship the Dark side of the Force. They however only exist in written canon.

For more examples of the appearances of deities a complete/near-complete list can be found [here](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Deity) under the appearances tab

Answer (score 2):

The movies all take "along time ago in a galaxy far, far away".

It's never been explained how the human race arrived in this galaxy, or how "Basic" (actually English) became such a common language. Many canon books reference a "belief" that humans originate on Coruscant, but it's far from certain.

One of my favorite theories is that the Earth galaxy eventually becomes uninhabitable, and the only other "habitable" galaxy they can find is one in the past. They travel there, (maybe settle on Coruscant), and evolve along with other species in the Star Wars galaxy.

ACTUAL ANSWER: with this backstory, it's easy to imagine "God" evolving as part of the English ("Basic") language. The people saying "God be with you", "Godforsaken", or "thank God" may not actually know what they're saying.

Comment: an interesting thought: in "Rebels" (the show), Ezra picks up the curse word "Karabast" from Zeb, a "Lasat". I'm not sure we ever find out what it literally translates to, so Ezra could be expressing something about the Lasat god without realizing it.